# Is there a data-driven WPF property grid/editor available? (preferably free)

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm looking for a data-driven WPF property grid/editor.

Most property grids appear to work using reflection to figure out the CLR properties on your class.  Those properties are then displayed in the grid with editors that are specific for the type of the property.

However I don't have a specific class that I want to plug into the property grid.  All I have is data, specifically a collection of name/value pairs.  I want to put this collection into the grid and have a editor that is specific for the value type of each pair.

Does anyone know of an existing property grid/editor control that supports data-driven properties?

Also if it looks like the property grid/editor in Blend I won't complain ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it, but from what I've read about the PropertyTools for WPF on codeplex.com supports dynamically editting the current selected object.

http://propertytools.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks.  This isn't exactly what I was after but after a quick overview of the code it looks like I might be able to customize the main class and expose access to the PropertyViewModel objects that are used internally to represent properties.